# Moodle: How I can disable course as like as units?

Tags: moodle

I'm working on moodle LMS. I wanna disble as like as units. I know courses have an option for show or hidden. But I wanna disable course. So user should be able see there are some course but there are disable (unavailable).
Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the permission `moodle/course:viewhiddencourses`to the logged in user role. That way they can see the hidden course. Additionally even if they do have permission to access all the courses it doesn't work on hidden courses so they stay disabled.

Comment: Thanks! :) where can I do this?

Comment: Thanks. I do that. But I still have problem. Because those are expandable and units are shown. so user can click and see them!